# react-packed-grid: null child is inserting a grid item

Tags: reactjs, grid

I have a problem that my data is returning an empty div even if it shouldn't display anything, which causes my design to be broken.

```js
      const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    
      const itemsToDisplay = data.slice(0, 5);
      const remainingItemsCount = data.length - itemsToDisplay.length;

      <PackedGrid boxAspectRatio={aspectRatio} className="fullscreen">
        {itemsToDisplay.map((i) => (
          <GridItemPlaceholder>{i}</GridItemPlaceholder>
        ))}
        {remainingItemsCount > 20 ? (
          <GridItemPlaceholder>+{remainingItemsCount}</GridItemPlaceholder>
        ) : null}
      </PackedGrid>`
```

The case above should return item 5 in the middle of the grid, but instead it's on left side and that's because `remainingItemsCount` is still returning an empty div on the right side of it. You can inspect the HTML to see it.

I wrote a condition that should stay null, but it does not work. I believe the issue is in the package I am using, but I figure there has to be some solution.

Here is my code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-16-9-ratio-forked-5qt1rx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The condition is nerver met, **data** has a length of `12` and **itemsToDisplay** has a length of `5` so **remainingItemsCount** is ... `7`. `7` is smaller than `20` and thus will return `null`

Comment: You should open an issue on `react-packed-grid` repo. For each `{null}` child, packed grid renders an empty container. Yes, you could work around it by mending your data into a cleaned-up array, but you definitely shouldn't have to!

Comment: `react-packed-grid`'s problem can be easily be noticed [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-16-9-ratio-forked-fk51mg). Side note: you made changes to your sandbox and it no longer displays the initial problem. This hinders your question's ability to be helpful to future users, which is one of [SO]'s governing principles. Please undo the changes in the sandbox and make it relevant for the question. Test potential solutions in a fork.

Comment: @tao yeah, sorry for fixing the repo - wasn't really thinking. I used a solution from below, which works in the case I showcased, but actually it does not work in real case scenario where I use component in return map function. Can be found in the original repo. I saw there's been a PR made quickly, I assume it's you. Thanks for help!

Comment: Yeah, no worries. I just realised I was only filtering out `null` values, not React components eventually resolving to `null`. I've updated my PR to deal with that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick for you

```
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

  const itemsToDisplay = data.slice(0, 5);
  const remainingItemsCount = data.length - itemsToDisplay.length;
  if (remainingItemsCount > 20) {
    itemsToDisplay.push(`+${remainingItemsCount}`)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <PackedGrid boxAspectRatio={aspectRatio} className="fullscreen">
        {itemsToDisplay.map((i) => (
          <GridItemPlaceholder>{i}</GridItemPlaceholder>
        ))}
      </PackedGrid>
    </>
  );
```